# Qt: Antialiasing of vertical text rendered using QPainter

Tags: c++, qt

I have implemented an oriented QPushButton (which is in my case a plot's axis label) similar to this example:
[Vertical QLabel, or the equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183050/vertical-qlabel-or-the-equivalent)
Here is the current paintEvent:

```
void OrientedPushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* ev) {

if (mOrientation == Qt::Vertical) {

    QPainter p(this);

    // support focus/hover styles
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);

    // text render hint
    p.setRenderHints(QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
    p.rotate(-90);

    QRect r(0, 0, -height(), width());
    p.drawText(r, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter, QPushButton::text());
}
else    // default drawing for horizontal buttons
    QPushButton::paintEvent(ev); 
}
```

The rendered QPushButtons look like this:

[image: screenshot]

Especially for the "A" one can see that the vertical QPushButton is rendered sharper. Is there a way, to render the vertical text such that the same anti-aliasing is applied as for horizontal text?

[EDIT] I tried the pixmap rendering proposed by @PavelStrakhov though this method applies anti-aliasing to vertical text, it cannot solve the Clear Type issue: [image: different text rendering]

Comment: Try to add p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

Comment: If you render horizontal text manually (instead of using default implementation), does it apply anti-aliasing correctly?

Comment: @Milovidov with `p.setRenderHints(QPainter::TextAntialiasing | QPainter::Antialiasing);` does not solve the issue

Comment: @PavelStrakhov thanks for adding the image. If I render the horizontal text on my own (without `p.rotate(-90);`) the anti-aliasing is the same as `QPushButton::paintEvent(ev);`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is also addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995703/qpainterrotate-disables-antialiasing-of-drawn-text), and it seems that there is (yet) no consistent cross-platform solution. You can create a pixmap and draw the text on it horizontally, then rotate the pixmap and draw it on the widget:

```
QPixmap pixmap(size());
pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
QPainter p2(&pixmap);
p2.setRenderHints(QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
p2.drawText(pixmap.rect(), Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter, 
            QPushButton::text());
p2.end();
pixmap = pixmap.transformed(QTransform().rotate(-90));
#todo: cache pixmap
#...
p.drawPixmap(rect(), pixmap);
```

Creating and rotating pixmaps is relatively expensive operation and should not be done at each repaint. But you can store it in a `QCache` or just in a member variable after first generation.

Comment: thanks for the hints. The related question and especially the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType#How_ClearType_works) article brought more insights. Unfortunately, the pixmap rendering does not solve the issue (the text gets very blurry) - and it seems to me now, that it might be best to wait for 4K monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar pixmap rendering issue. When I drew text on a pixmap using QPainter, the result pixmap was blurred with low quality. After some investigation in Qt source code, I fixed the issue by finding the system device pixel ratio and setting it on pixmap before calling painter.drawText(...).

```
    /*
     * The following code is to avoid low quality blur pixmap created via
     * QPainter, sample code is found in QAbstractItemViewPrivate::renderToPixmap method
     */
    qreal scale = 1.0;
    QWidget *window = this->window();
    if (window) {
        QWindow *windowHandle = window->windowHandle();
        if (windowHandle) {
            scale = windowHandle->devicePixelRatio();
        }
    }
    QPixmap pixmap(pixmapRect.size() * scale);
    pixmap.setDevicePixelRatio(scale);
```

Hope it helps.